# flask how to pass variable to url for different domain

Tags: python, flask

I've built a Flask app, and I'm trying to figure out how to pass a variable into a link that is not hosted by me. Concretely, it's a completely different website that I have no control over.

I've tried

```
<a href="http://domainname.org/{{ variable }}"> Link </a>
```

However this did not capture the `{{ variable}}` , and in fact just resulted in domain.com.

I've looked into `url_for` but that only seems to work when its for your own website? I think?
e.g. localhost. This particular link prefix is for a completely different domain and host.

Any help appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Could you share some example code? When you call `render_template` you can pass variables to it and then access them on your template using `{{  }}` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the `variable` variable to your render template.

Eg:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", variable="whatever")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Then in index.html:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Your title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://domainname.org/{{variable}}">Link</a> <!-- This will go to http://domainname.org/whatever -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is precisely what I did, but when the webapp loaded up it just ignored the variable and the link resulted in just domainname.org.